# Parsing HTML in Python

Tags: python, html-parsing

What's my best bet for parsing HTML if I can't use BeautifulSoup or lxml? I've got some code that uses SGMLlib but it's a bit low-level and it's now deprecated.

I would prefer if it could stomache a bit of malformed HTML although I'm pretty sure most of the input will be pretty clean.

Comment: If I may ask, why can't you use lxml, or BS?

Comment: I was trying to avoid answers getting completely sidetracked. My reasons for avoiding BeautifulSoup are hugely debatable but I was saving that for another day!

(My reasons for avoiding lxml are simple - a complete failure to install it on either Mac OSX or Linux :(

Comment: Here is how to install lxml on Linux: `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev python2.7-dev` (`python2.6-dev` if you use Python 2.6). Then `sudo pip install lxml`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Python has a [native HTML parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html), however the Tidy wrapper Nick suggested would probably be a solid choice as well. Tidy is a very common library, (written in C is it?)

Comment: Can someone please tell me as to why do people suggest BeautifulSoup or lxml over the native HTML parser?

Comment: Link is broken… I gues this is [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)? Or the [version for legacy Python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/htmlparser.html).

Comment: The module is still there, the URL appears to have changed though. Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps [µTidylib](http://utidylib.berlios.de/) will meet your needs?

Answer (score 2):

You can install lxml and many other python modules easily and seamlessly on the Mac (OS X) using Pallet, which is the [MacPorts official GUI](https://trac.macports.org/wiki/MacPortsGUI)

The module name is py27-lxml. Easy as 1,2,3.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.xmlhack.com/read.php?item=1392
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pirxx/

http://pyxml.sourceforge.net/topics/

I don't have much experience with python, but I have used Xerces (from the Apache foundation) in the past and found it to be very useful. The learning curve isn't bad either, though I'm not coming from a python perspective. I suggest you consider it though. (The first two links I've included discuss python interfaces to Xerces and the last one is the first google hit on "python xml").

Comment: I know you want an HTML parser, but these will be good starting places.

Answer (score 1):

html5lib is good:
http://code.google.com/p/html5lib/

**Update:** The link above is broken. A third-party mirror of above, can be accessed from https://github.com/html5lib/gcode-import

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: This isn't *quite* a link-only answer, @Dgw. It contains a complete sentence mentioning the name of the linked-to library, and in the case of this question, the name of a library *is* the essential part of the answer. Anyone can search for it in case the link is dead.

Answer (score 1):

htql is good at handling malformed html:

http://htql.net/