# ElemenTree error, prestashop - openerp connector module

Tags: python, xml, parsing, odoo, prestashop

I'm using the `prestashop-openerp` connector [launchpad site](https://launchpad.net/prestashoperpconnect)

Could install everyhting, no errors, but when i try to `connect` with my remote `prestashop` website interface It throws this error:

```
ParseError: mismatched tag: line 13, column 2
```

And the Server traceback:

```
Server Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 89, in send
return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 292, in dispatch_rpc
result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 626, in dispatch
res = fn(db, uid, *params)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 188, in execute_kw
return self.execute(db, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw or {})
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 131, in wrapper
return f(self, dbname, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 197, in execute
res = self.execute_cr(cr, uid, obj, method, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/osv.py", line 185, in execute_cr
return getattr(object, method)(cr, uid, *args, **kw)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashop_model.py", line 103, in synchronize_metadata
import_batch(session, model, backend_id)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashoperpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 663, in import_batch
importer.run(filters=filters, **kwargs)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashoperpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 176, in run
record_ids = self._run_page(filters)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashoperpconnect/unit/import_synchronizer.py", line 184, in _run_page
record_ids = self.backend_adapter.search(filters)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/prestashoperpconnect/unit/backend_adapter.py", line 126, in search
return api.search(self._prestashop_model, filters)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 494, in search
search(resource, options=options)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 348, in search
return self.get(resource, options=options)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 516, in get
response = super(PrestaShopWebServiceDict, self).get(resource, resource_id=resource_id, options=options)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 366, in get
return self.get_with_url(full_url)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 536, in get_with_url
response = super(PrestaShopWebServiceDict, self).get_with_url(url)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 375, in get_with_url
r = self._execute(url, 'GET')
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 206, in _execute
self._check_status_code(r.status_code, r.content)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 144, in _check_status_code
ps_error_code, ps_error_msg = self._parse_error(content)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 116, in _parse_error
error_answer = self._parse(xml_content)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 619, in _parse
parsed_content = super(PrestaShopWebServiceDict, self)._parse(content)
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 227, in _parse
parsed_content = ElementTree.fromstring(unicode_encode.unicode2encoding(content))
File "<string>", line 124, in XML
```

I've searched for some answer, saw this [question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9672448/urllib-combined-together-with-elementtree) but still no clue.

IDK if this is actually a bug of the module, or the `prestapyt` library, i really don't know, or maybe an error with some `xml` in my prestashop install.

Anybody have used this module, or has any clue about this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT

This was an outdated version of prestapyt, now i have the last one, and the traceback error is more clear:

```
  parsed_content = super(PrestaShopWebServiceDict, self)._parse(content)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/prestapyt-0.6.0-py2.7.egg/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 214, in _parse
raise PrestaShopWebServiceError('HTTP XML response is not parsable : %s. %s' % (e, content[:512]))
  PrestaShopWebServiceError: 'HTTP XML response is not parsable : mismatched tag: line 13, column 2. <HTML>\n<HEAD>\n<TITLE>404 Not Found</TITLE>\n</HEAD>\n<BODY>\n<H1>Not Found</H1>\nThe requested document was not found on this server.\n<P>\n<HR>\n<ADDRESS>\nWeb Server at taxco.com.ve\n</ADDRESS>\n</BODY>\n</HTML>\n\n<!--\n   - Unfortunately, Microsoft has added a clever new\n   - "feature" to Internet Explorer. If the text of\n   - an error\'s message is "too small", specifically\n   - less than 512 bytes, Internet Explorer returns\n   - its own error message. You can turn that off,\n   - but it\'s pretty tricky to find switch'
```

It's a `404` error, but i don't know which file should be added there, someone with experience implementing this connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already have (almost) all the clues in the error message and traceback: prestapit is getting some malformed / broken XML. The missing clue are: which url does return malformed XML and what does this broken XML looks like.

If you look at your traceback, there's an obvious place where you can get at both tyhe url and the response :

```
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 375, in get_with_url
r = self._execute(url, 'GET')
File "/usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py", line 206, in _execute
self._check_status_code(r.status_code, r.content)
```

So from line =~205 of /usr/prestaconnect/prestashoperpconnect/src/prestapyt/prestapyt/prestapyt.py you can either print or log the url and response for inspection, or just add a breakpoint to get into the debugger (if not running in daemon mode obviously).

Comment: Thank you for your guidelines, i'm debugging it with pdb, but i think i have to download the .py from author github, think mine it's an outdated version. I'll check

Comment: Yes, it was outdated, it throws me the error anyway, but it's quite more 'verbose' for a saying.

Comment: It was a problem with webservice on server side, and of course an outdated version of prestapyt. Thank you!