# How to parse the html file from python?

Tags: python

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Parsing HTML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python)

i am newbie to python, i am using python.i have downloaded the HTML file from my site.and that downloaded HTML file has some urls. i want only some urls from that HTML file to be write in to separate text file using python.how can i do this? can anyone help me?

Comment: See This Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/).

> Beautiful Soup is a Python library for pulling data out of HTML and XML files. It works with your favorite parser to provide idiomatic ways of navigating, searching, and modifying the parse tree. It commonly saves programmers hours or days of work.