# python html parsing

Tags: python

I have the following problem:

I would like to parse html files and get links from the html file. I can get links with the following code:

```
class MyHTMLParser(HTMLParser):
    links=[]
    def __init__(self,url):
        HTMLParser.__init__(self)
        self.url = url

    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        try: 
            if tag == 'a':
                for name, value in attrs:
                    if name == 'href':
                        if value[:5]=="http:":
                            self.links.append(value)
        except: 
            pass
```

But I dont want to get audio files, video files, etc. I only want to get html links. How can I do that?

Comment: I can check link ending and if it is particular format I can avoid appending that link to the list. Is there other way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can check link ending and if it is particular format I can avoid
>   appending that link to the list. Is there other way?

You could look at the `'Content-Type'` header:

```
import urllib2
url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13431060/python-html-parsing'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'    
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
content_type = response.headers.getheader('Content-Type')
print(content_type)
```

yields

```
text/html; charset=utf-8
```

---

Many thanks to @JonClements for `req.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD'`. More info on this and alternate methods for sending a HEAD request can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/107405/190597).

Comment: Instead of using `Range` - I'd probably go for `request = urllib2.Request(someurl); request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD';  response = urllib2.urlopen(request)` and continue from there...

Comment: @JonClements: Thank you very much for the info. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: @JonClements: What does it mean for `req.get_method()` to return `HEAD`? [The docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request.get_method) seem to say it always returns `GET` or `POST`...?

Comment: If a payload is present in the request, then `get_method` is `POST` otherwise it's a `GET` - replacing the method is a very kludgly way of writing `requests.head(url)`...