# Regular expression extract and exclude data from string

Tags: python, regex

I have an html like string I want to extract data out of.

```
s="<ul><li>this is a bullet lev 1&nbsp;</li><li><ul><li><strong>&nbsp;this</strong> is a bullet lev&nbsp;</li></ul></li><li>&nbsp;<ul><li><ul><li>this is a bullet lev 3</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></ul><strong></li>
```

"

I want to extract the content of all *data* containing <li> elements, these are elements that contain something like "this is a bullet lev 1 " between them and not those that contains other <li> as in multilevel elements such as

```
<li><ul><li><strong>&nbsp;this</strong> is a bullet lev&nbsp;</li></ul></li>
```

I have written a regular expression for that

```
<li>([\w &;/<>]*?)</li>
```

however this ends up pulling the unwanted data as well

```
<li>this is a bullet lev 1&nbsp;</li>
<li><ul><li><strong>&nbsp;this</strong> is a bullet lev&nbsp;</li>
<li>&nbsp;<ul><li><ul><li>this is a bullet lev 3</li>
```

while I want it to pull

```
<li>this is a bullet lev 1&nbsp;</li>
<li><strong>&nbsp;this</strong> is a bullet lev&nbsp;</li>
<li>&nbsp;<ul><li><ul><li>this is a bullet lev 3</li>
```

The idea is that I want to exclude any results that already have  <li> in the extracted data and move ahead.

From research i understood I probably have to use a lookahead or a lookbehind and I gave it a couple of tries but to no avail.

Any clues? I am using python and it builtin re module.

Comment: Why are you not using a HTML parser instead?

Comment: Please read this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

and this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this might do the job.

```
<li>((?!<li>).)*?</li>
```

Should match any `<li>` followed by `</li>` and anything in between as long as they don't contain a `<li>` (using a [lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html))

This assumes that you don't actually want `<li>&nbsp;<ul><li><ul><li>this is a bullet lev 3</li>`, but rather: `<li>this is a bullet lev 3</li>`, in your examples, which seems more consistent with your description.

That said, a parser really would be a better idea for this sort of thing, generally speaking.

Comment: That's awesome!! That did the trick. Thanks a lot. I evaluated the parser idea but there is a problem with that (I assume you mean an html parser). The data I am receiving is not strictly speaking correctly formatted for HTML parsing so I gave up tht idea. Again, thank's so much. I will take any other options though, I understand what I am doing is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

I've never used BeautifulSoup before but I installed it and without reading any documentation, within 15 minutes:

```
>>> s="<ul><li>this is a bullet lev 1&nbsp;</li><li><ul><li><strong>&nbsp;this</strong> is a bullet lev&nbsp;</li></ul></li><li>&nbsp;<ul><li><ul><li>this is a bullet lev 3</li></ul></li></ul></li></ul></ul><strong></li>"
>>> from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(s)
>>> for liRaw in soup.findAll('li'):
...   if liRaw.findParent().findParent().name == u'[document]':
...     print liRaw.text
this is a bullet lev 1&nbsp;
&nbsp;thisis a bullet lev&nbsp;
&nbsp;this is a bullet lev 3
```

Hope this helps...

Comment: Hi there, what I gave as an example above is a correctly formatted example.  I evaluated the parser idea but there is a problem with that. The data I am receiving is not strictly speaking correctly formatted for HTML parsing so I gave up tht idea, however I understand what I am doing is not efficient The parser I tried is the default xml.dom.minidom and not beautifulsoup. I will give that a try as a plan B. Thanks a lot for you suggestion.

Comment: might be worth running a proper test with data that is more realistic.  Most good html parsers can couple with a similar level of malformedness that a real browser can.  For example I just tried removing all the ``</li>`` tags from your example string ``s`` and it worked fine, with the same results. I'll certainly be baring BeautifulSoup in mind for future projects