# Printing the html from one page doen't show all the source page with python and urllib2

Tags: python, html, html-parsing, urllib2

i'm trying to read on specific page from amazon.

```
req = urllib2.Request('http://www.amazon.com/Upright-Citizens-Brigade-Comedy-Improvisation/dp/0989387801/ref=lp_1_1_6/175-0367440-7496156?ie=UTF8&qid=1376827779&sr=1-6%20buybox._V181901516_.png)%20center%20top%20no-repeat;')
req.add_header('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0\
            (Windows NT 6.2; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.11 (KHTML, like Gecko)\
            Chrome/23.0.1271.97 Safari/537.11')
response=urllib2.urlopen(req)
html = response.read()
print html
```

i'm trying to read the price from a new item "$25.00" that's showed in the source code of the page but that part doesn't show in the html print. what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You should be able to replace the current request url with this: `http://www.amazon.com/Upright-Citizens-Brigade-Comedy-Improvisation/dp/0989387801/`, then just parse the html to find the price. There are a number of helpful answers here: [Parsing HTML Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python).

Answer (score 2):

You should use an html parser, like [lxml](http://lxml.de) or [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/). Here's an example using `lxml`:

```
parser = etree.HTMLParser()
root = etree.fromstring(html, parser=parser)

print root.xpath('//td[@class="a-text-right dp-new-col"]/a/span/text()')[0]
```

prints:

```
$25.00
```

Note, that the required tag and it's value was found using [xpath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) expression:

> XPath, the XML Path Language, is a query language for selecting nodes
>   from an XML document.

Also see:

- [Parsing HTML using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11709079/parsing-html-python)
- [Parsing HTML in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python)

Hope that helps.