# Python parsing html for complete links urls

Tags: python, hyperlink, html-parsing

I have to parse a html page looking for links in it. Unfortunately, the links don't contain the full url (for instance starting with "http://www.example.com/aResource.html"). So my parsing get only the relative URL, for get the whole url address i'm using

```
urlparse.urljoin()
```

But often it leads to some connection errors, and generally i would prefer a direct way to extract the comlplete urls link. Here is my code:

```
import urlparse
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

aFile = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(aFile.text)

linkList = tree.xpath('//a')

urls = []

for link in linkList:
    urls.append(str(urlparse.urljoin(url,link.get('href'))))
```

As you can see i'm working with lxml, but i've also tried with BeautifulSoup without success.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717541/parsing-html-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  The url is something like that: http://example.com/path/0VPZUJL06JKS/U09R71.html. And in the link tag are specified just the element from the last "/"

Comment: @user2567853 You mean that the schema (http://) is missing ?

Comment: @Cld I mean that this part is missing: "http://example.com/path/0VPZUJL06JKS/"

Comment: And this part is not in your "main" URL ? In this case the problem is not in the code but in the page who can't even work in a browser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the information (URL scheme, host server, port, path - base URL) is missing in `<a href=""...>`, it needs to be added to the relative URL.

Usually it is correct to use `urlparse.urljoin()` as you are already doing.

HTML does allow specification of a base url for the page using the `<base href="...">` tag, which must be defined once in `<head>`. If this tag is present you should use it's href attribute as your base URL for `urljoin()`. Your code could be revised to this:

```
import urlparse
import requests
from lxml import html
from lxml import etree

aFile = requests.get(url)
tree = html.fromstring(aFile.text)

linkList = tree.xpath('//a')

urls = []

try:
    base_url = tree.xpath('//base[1]/@href')[0]
except IndexError:
    base_url = url

for link in linkList:
    urls.append(str(urlparse.urljoin(base_url,link.get('href'))))
```

However, if you are getting connection errors, it would appear that some of the links are invalid. Either the base URL derived from the page's URL, or from the `<base href="...">` tag, is correct. Any invalid URLs constructed with this value must be due to an invalid relative URL (or invalid `<base>` tag).

Have you concrete examples of the URL used when connection errors are experienced?

You could also look at [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/):

```
import mechanize

br = mechanize.Browser()
resp = br.open(url)
urls = [link.absolute_url for link in br.links()]
```

Comment: What was the problem?